# Relationship between field and multiple table in MS-ACESS

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a doubt about a relationship that i think is complex. For example, i want to know in which PCB i use electronics components. So, i have three tables (UsedOn, Resistors and Capacitors):

```
UsedOn:
   PartID
   PCBID

Resistors:
   PartID;
   ...

Capacitors:
   PartID;
   ...
```

The question is: In relationship i can i identify from which table PartID is?

I have tried to link to both tables, but in this case each line will have 1 resistor and 1 capacitor, and is not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your design. Your 3 tables should be UsedOn(PCBID, PartID, PcbDescription), Parts(PartID, PartTypeID, PartDescription), PartTypes(PartTypeID, PartTypeDescription). PartTypeDescription would be resistors, capacitors, etc.)
Then relate PartTypes to Parts and Parts to UsedOn.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to redesign your tables. I would suggest:

**tblComponentType**: ComponentTypeID, ComponentType (*This table will store the type of component, such as resistor or capacitor*);

**tblComponent**: ComponentID, ComponentTypeID, ComponentName (*This table will store information about the components, and because it has a many:one relationship to tblComponentType we know what sort of component it is*);

**tblPCB**: PCBID, PCBName (*This table will store information about the PCBs*);

**tblPCBComponents**: PCBComponentID, PCBID, ComponentID, Quantity (*This is a "junction" table that tells us what components are used in which PCBs*).

You can then create a query that joins these 4 tables together

Regards,

Comment: but i have a question. It's possible to have different tables for different types of components? Because i need it

Comment: You could, but it will probably get messy. Why do you need it?

Comment: I use this tables in other software. This software doesn't allow to filter for ComponentType, and i use the tables to identify each category. Each component type have it's characteristics too.